# shopping website with mongodb

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

I am programming a shopping web site now, but there are things in my mind that I cannot solve,

Products will have at least 5 pictures, and I need to put them in folders, in mysql, with the primary key of the product, the folder structure would be like this,

```
for example the product id is, 756234,

so the path to the picture would be,

image.example.com/75/62/34/product.jpg
```

The problem is, right now I am using mongodb, and Mongodb's objectid's are very different and they change everytime, how can I make a folder structure like this ? any solutions ? thank you :)

Comment: At product creation time, generate a random integer. Now you can use mysql's solution.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal the product id is 756234, so the folder structure would be 75/62/34

Comment: @SergioTulentsev random integer might appear twice or more, my costumer says It is going to have at least 1 million products, It should be perfect, It can end or rise my career

Comment: So, after generation, check if it matches any existing files. If so, regenerate

Comment: @SergioTulentsev this one looks okay, but there will be at least one million, after 300.000 this might be a headache. Like this, 30/00/00, I should check for database everytime, I am thinking of this one, I will insert empty to only get the primary key, after insertion I will delete the row, I don't think this will be a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is maintain another attribute and make it a unique index, and maintain the autoincement value in another collection, so that it can be used to insert new documents. That way, you will still stick to your old autoincrement keys and you don't need to worry about your URL structure.

Comment: I might use this one thank you :)

Comment: Also, remember to use `findAndModify` to make atomic fetches and updates to the autoincrement stores.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need folder structure, you can use PHP router on image.example.com. For instance use Code Ignitor.

Make a controller with a function index, put 75, 62, 34, product.jpg into params of the function as $p1, $p2 , $p3 , $name

Upload files on root as:

```
756234product.jpg
```

Generate Image URL like this:

```
'http://image.example.com' . '/'. $p1 . $p2 . $p3 . $name;
```

Access it like this:

```
http://image.example.com/75/62/34/product.jpg
```

Comment: Serve static assets with PHP? I don't think so :)

Comment: Yes I too don't think so, but you will get rid of directories.

Comment: I want to create a folder structure, 75, 62, 34 are folder names that can change according to primary key.

Answer (score 1):

mongodb ids is little longer than your id  (like 507f1f77bcf86cd799439011) but its unique for each collection. you can use it as folder name without any problems

Comment: It is going to be more than a million folders, I cannot put them in a folder

Comment: you can use product creation date to create dir structure. like
<code>
/12-03-2013
   /507f1f77bcf86cd799439011
   /GDGRGDG7bcf86cd799445635</code>

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in Mongo, that prevents you from assigning your own ids. Mongo will honour any unique value, that you pass to it.
Another way is to fold the long id. E.g. by taking them modulo 1000000, which will give you your six digit key for the image.

Why do you think, the id of MongoBD changes? Not as far as i know.

Comment: yes you can assign your own ids, but how you are going to do that ?, the id of mongodb changes to keep the id unique, so that means, I cannot structure my folders like the given example